# How to remove url id from Joomla! 3.1.1 Stable

Tags: html, url, joomla, joomla3.1

How to remove Universal Resource Locator(url) id from Joomla! 3.1.1 Stable?

Comment: Create menu item to that article.

Comment: sorry i did not get you... pleases

Comment: @piotr_cz but it coming a drop down i don't need that drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla Menu system allows you to create custom urls:

**Create menu item to the article with an alias you pick.**

If you don't want that menu item to be shown on the site:

1. Create new Menu called 'Hidden' *(Menus > Menu Manager > Add new Menu)*
2. Move the item there *(open menu item > Menu Location > Hidden)*
3. Don't create a module for this menu *(or if it has been created automatically on Joomla 1.5 - 2.5 unpublish it in Module manager)*